# How to make bulk update with arrays in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In **PostgreSQL** database I have table called `services` which has 4 columns. Is it possible to make a mass update via arrays? I tried such code but it raise error:

```
SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE
```

SQL:

```
UPDATE SERVICES
SET
    NAME = UNNEST(ARRAY['NAME OF THE FIRST SERVICE', 'NAME OF THE SECOND SERVICE']),
    ACTIVE = UNNEST(ARRAY[FALSE, TRUE]),
    DESCRIPTION = UNNEST(ARRAY['DESCRIPTION OF THE FIRST SERVICE', 'DESCRIPTION OF THE SECOND SERVICE'])
WHERE
    ID = UNNEST(ARRAY['e1433cd2-7591-4a74-b910-33ea89d87ecd', '6c27c413-4be2-4a89-bea0-e713445ebfe1']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unnest them in a subquery:

```
UPDATE services s
    SET name = x.name,
        active = x.active,
        description = x.description
FROM (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['NAME OF THE FIRST SERVICE', 'NAME OF THE SECOND SERVICE']) as name,
             UNNEST(ARRAY[FALSE, TRUE]) as active,
             UNNEST(ARRAY['DESCRIPTION OF THE FIRST SERVICE', 'DESCRIPTION OF THE SECOND SERVICE']) as description
             UNNEST(ARRAY['e1433cd2-7591-4a74-b910-33ea89d87ecd', '6c27c413-4be2-4a89-bea0-e713445ebfe1']) as id
     ) x
WHERE s.id = x.id;
```

When there are multiple `unnest()`s in a single `select`, Postgres unnests them in parallel (rather than generating a Cartesian product).  The number of rows is the number of rows of the biggest array, with shorter arrays being padded with `null`s.

Comment: I think you miss `SET` keyword in your SQL statement. In my case type of `ID` column is `uuid`. When I try to test your code it raise error: `ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = text`. Do you have any ideas about it?

Comment: As I understand array of ids must be like this: `UNNEST(ARRAY[uuid('e1433cd2-7591-4a74-b910-33ea89d87ecd'), uuid('6c27c413-4be2-4a89-bea0-e713445ebfe1')])`.

Comment: Also other way is `UNNEST(ARRAY['e1433cd2-7591-4a74-b910-33ea89d87ecd', '6c27c413-4be2-4a89-bea0-e713445ebfe1']::uuid[])`